# Which software tools from LatticeSemiconductor do I need to develop design with iCE40 LP FPGA?

Tags: fpga, lattice

There are a lot of programs that can be found here:

https://www.latticesemi.com/en/Products/DesignSoftwareAndIP

Which of these do I need for creating a design with iCE40 LP FPGA?

The reason for my confusion is that we merely need Quartus Prime for Intel and Libero SoC for Microsemi. However, when it comes to Lattice Semiconductor, there is a lot of choice.

Comment: I tried to send a support request to them but their automated system did not accept it due to the nature of the question. They used to have support forums that have now been shut down. I am new to this stuff, I don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask Lattice, [you'll need their ICEcube2 suite](http://www.latticesemi.com/en/Products/FPGAandCPLD/iCE40?ActiveTab=Data+Sheet#_BB6ACE16A22443A1B2317A9A66203E62). The ICE 40 getting started documentation lists all that, I'll leave reading that bit of Lattice's website up to you!

However, if you ask the rest of the world: The [ICEStudio](https://icestudio.io/) is a free and open source IDE for these FPGAs. It uses the yosys synthesis suite, nextpnr or arachnepnr for place and route and supports a few programmers out of the box. It supports popular ICE40 devboards out of the box.

Comment: What are the other programs used for: Lattice Diamond, Lattice Radiant, Lattice Propel, 
 ispLEVER Classic, Lattice Sense AI, LatticeMicoSystem, ​PAC_Designer Design Software?

Comment: 99% of the stuff these day is done with diamond. isplever is for the old stuff, the other are for specialized product lines

Comment: I hope you found the right tools. Anyway, I think @LorenzoMarcantonio has it right.